# Passing colours from JSON file loader into faces

Tags: json, three.js

I'm programmatically generating a json file to load a mesh, the vertices and faces render fine but I can't figure out how to pass colours through to the faces as well.

Here's the json file that I'm experimenting with:

```
{
    "metadata" : {
        "formatVersion" : 3
    },
    "materials" : [],
    "vertices" : [-10,10,0, -10,-10,0, 10,-10,0, 10,10,0, -10,10,10,  -10,-10,10,  10,-10,10,  10,10,10],
    "faces" : [4, 0, 1, 3, 0], //or with 0 as the first number for a plain triangle
    "normals": [],
    "colors": [0.5, 0.4, 0.3],
    "uvs": []
}
```

And loading like so:

```
loader.load( "js/models/square.js", function(geometry) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
        faceColors : THREE.FaceColors,
    });
    material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}
```

My central problem is that I'm stumbling over how the bitmask works, but the FACE_COLOR bit here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3.1 suggests that it should work, any help would be much appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to construct your JSON file correctly. This simplest example is something like this, which defines a cube with face colors:

```
{
    "metadata" : {
        "formatVersion" : 3
    },
    "materials" : [],
    "vertices" : [ -5,5,-5,  -5,-5,-5,  5,-5,-5,  5,5,-5,  -5,5,5,  -5,-5,5,  5,-5,5,  5,5,5 ],
    "faces" : [ 65,3,2,1,0,0,  65,4,5,6,7,1,  65,7,6,2,3,2,  65,0,1,5,4,3,  65,0,4,7,3,0,  65,6,5,1,2,1 ],
    "colors": [ 16711680, 65280, 255, 16776960 ],
    "normals": [],
    "uvs": []
}
```

In this example, each face is assigned one of four face colors. The colors are specified in decimal format, e.g., 0xff0000 = 16711680.

The bitmask code for each face is 64 (for face colors) + 1 (for quad) = 65.

Then, since you have not specified vertex normals, I assume what you want is `MeshBasicMateral`. Also, there is no "faceColors" property -- it's `vertexColors`. And, you have to remember to add your mesh to the scene.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load( "cube.js", function( geometry ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
        vertexColors : THREE.FaceColors,
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
}
```

three.js r.53